# Multiple-language document - babel - selectlanguage vs begin/end{otherlanguage}

Tags: environments, babel

What's the difference in [`babel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel?lang=en) package between:

```
\selectlanguage{languageA}
```

and

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{languageB}
Text in language B.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

?

I'd like to write a two-language-document where I will have whole chapters in one or the other language, each in a separate included file.

Which method of language switching is more appropriate in my case?

Comment: I would use `\selectlanguage`. The environment creates a group which is probably unnessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is if you also want to change the date format and e.g. the chapter headings, when you have chapters. If yes, then use `\selectlanguage`. If you want to keep the date format and chapter headers like "Chapter", then use the environment `otherlanguage*` or for a short text the command `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: +1 for : "The question is if you also want to change the date format and eg the chapter headings, if pyou have chapters. If yes, then use \selectlanguage." - this part is crucial in my case :).

Answer (score 11):

The `\selectlanguage` command and the `otherlanguage` environment have the same functionality: change all language-related settings; the difference is that the environment defines a group so the language change is local to the environment.

In your case, since the changes must apply to whole chapters, I'd probably go with `\selectlanguage`, unless intermixing
left-to-right typesetting with right-to-left typesetting is required, in which case the environment would be better according to `babel` documentation:

> The environment `otherlanguage` does basically the same as
>   `\selectlanguage`, except the language change is local to the
>   environment. This environment is required for intermixing
>   left-to-right typesetting with right-to-left typesetting.

There's also an `otherlanguage*` environment in which the typesetting is done according to the rules of the other language, but the text-strings such as "figure", "table", etc. are left as they were set outside this environment.

Comment: a lot of useful information :).